# Suppress Bootstrap Dismissable Popover Border Highlighting

Tags: css-selectors, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

When clicking on a link (or button) to display a dismissible popover, the border of the clicked element is highlighted. This occurs with the [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#dismiss-on-next-click) from the Bootstrap documentation and my page in practice. (FYI, I plan to replace my text "[ i ]" with an image; my assumption is that the highlighted element is the `href` and not the text.)

##### Bootstrap 5 Docs Dismissible Popover Button

[image: Bootstrap 5 Dismissible Popover Button Image]

##### My DismissIble Popover

[image: My Dismissible Popover href]

In the Bootstrap Docs example, the following is added to the element when the button is clicked:

```html
aria-describedby="popover808202"
```

##### My Code

```html
<div class="tile-title">
  Modified<span style="float:right;"><a tabindex="0" href="#" title="Help" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-content="Descriptive and useful information can be displayed here.">[ i ]</a></span>
</div>
```

##### My JavaScript

```js
let popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
let popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
let popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.popover-dismiss'), {
  trigger: 'focus'
})
```

##### Desired Result

I would like to suppress the highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was easier than I thought.

```css
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

This example will of course disable anchor highlighting completely (for all anchors that use the CSS properties above) for the entire page.